# Processing: void draw() function source

Tags: java, processing

I am looking for the source code of `void draw()` function in Processing. 
Any suggestion ?

thank you

Comment: What you mean by Processing ?

Comment: _Processing_ software, I found this link https://github.com/processing/processing

Comment: but I do not find the source code about the void draw().

Comment: I mean how it is written

Comment: https://github.com/processing/processing/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=draw&type=Code

Comment: thank you, I would like to re-write a (loop) draw function in Haskell and I need to understand how it is built.

Comment: This is question might be off-topic here, refer [on-topic before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code for the entire Processing library on GitHub [here](https://github.com/processing/processing).

[Here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java) is a direct link to the `PApplet` class, which defines the `draw()` function. Search for "void draw" to find this:

```
public void draw() {
    // if no draw method, then shut things down
    //System.out.println("no draw method, goodbye");
    finished = true;
  }
```

There isn't much to it, and that's because you're supposed to define your own `draw()` function that **overrides** this one. That's how Processing works. **You** write the code for the `draw()` function.

**Edit**: Judging by your comment, I'm guessing that you're trying to understand how Processing calls the `draw()` function 60 times per second. That's a little bit more complicated.

Check out [`PSurfaceAWT`](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/awt/PSurfaceAWT.java), which is the default renderer used in Processing. Search for "handleDraw" to find this bit of code:

```
public Thread createThread() {
    return new AnimationThread() {
      @Override
      public void callDraw() {
        sketch.handleDraw();
        render();
      }
    };
  }
```

AnimationThread is defined in the [`PSurfaceNone`](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PSurfaceNone.java) class:

```
public class AnimationThread extends Thread {

    public AnimationThread() {
      super("Animation Thread");
    }

    public void callDraw() {
      sketch.handleDraw();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {  
      long beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
      long overSleepTime = 0L;

      int noDelays = 0;
      final int NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD = 15;

      sketch.start();

      while ((Thread.currentThread() == thread) && !sketch.finished) {
        checkPause();

        callDraw();

        long afterTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timeDiff = afterTime - beforeTime;
        long sleepTime = (frameRatePeriod - timeDiff) - overSleepTime;

        if (sleepTime > 0) {  // some time left in this cycle
          try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime / 1000000L, (int) (sleepTime % 1000000L));
            noDelays = 0;  // Got some sleep, not delaying anymore
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }

          overSleepTime = (System.nanoTime() - afterTime) - sleepTime;

        } else {    // sleepTime <= 0; the frame took longer than the period
          overSleepTime = 0L;
          noDelays++;

          if (noDelays > NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD) {
            Thread.yield();   // give another thread a chance to run
            noDelays = 0;
          }
        }

        beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
      }

      sketch.dispose(); 

      // If the user called the exit() function, the window should close,
      // rather than the sketch just halting.
      if (sketch.exitCalled) {
        sketch.exitActual();
      }
    }
  }
```

I've removed some commented-out sections. This might seem like a lot of code, but all it's really doing is setting up a Thread that fires 60 times per second by measuring how much time has passed and sleeping the correct amount. A more basic example would be something like this:

```
new Thread(){
   public void run(){
      while(true){
         draw();
         Thread.sleep(16);
      }
   }
}
```

Those are the basics, but it can get much more involved than that. I recommend googling "animation thread" or "game loop" or "game animation thread" and trying something out.